# Rails3 Ajax form (jquery) and model validation

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, validation, forms

i send an form remotely and wanted to add a validation to it. this is in my model:

```
  validates :email, :presence => true, :email => true
```

validation works fine, when email is valid it adds it to the database, if not, then not. my problem is, whenever i submit the form, it renders my subscribe.js file:

```
$('.form').html("<p><strong>Thank you for your interest!<br />We'll keep you up-to-date.</strong></p>");
```

how can i tell rails, that if the email adress is unvalid, it should render another .js file? or is there another way?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this...

```
if @object.save 
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
else   
  render # something else
end
```